# How to delete all images in all repositories except in one repository named "devops" in gcloud platform

Tags: image, repository, gcloud, except

I have the code to delete all images in a repository except the latest 6 images,but i want to take the script to next level which deletes all images in repositories except a repository named "devops"..

````sh
IFS=$'\n\t'
set -eou pipefail

if [[ "$#" -ne 2 || "${1}" == '-h' || "${1}" == '--help' ]]; then
    cat >&2 <<"EOF"

EOF
    exit 1
# elif [ ${2} -ge 0 ] 2>/dev/null; then
#     echo "no number of images to remain given" >&2
#     exit 1
fi

main() {
    local C=0
    IMAGE="${1}"
    NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_TO_REMAIN=$((${2} - 1))

    DATE=$(gcloud container images list-tags $IMAGE --limit=unlimited \
        --sort-by=~TIMESTAMP --format=json | TZ=/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC jq -r '.['$NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_TO_REMAIN'].timestamp.datetime | sub("(?<before>.*):"; .before ) | strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z") | mktime | strftime("%Y-%m-%d")')

    for digest in $(gcloud container images list-tags $IMAGE --limit=unlimited --sort-by=~TIMESTAMP \
        --filter="timestamp.datetime < '${DATE}'" --format='get(digest)'); do
        (
            set -x
            gcloud container images delete -q --force-delete-tags "${IMAGE}@${digest}"
        )
        let C=C+1
    done
    echo "Deleted ${C} images in ${IMAGE}." >&2
}

main "${1}" ${2}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's confusing but, Google Container Registry differs from other Google Cloud Platform services in that it represents an implementation of a 3rd-party (Docker) Registry API.

For this reason, there is no set of Google (!) client libraries for managing images in Container Registry and unlike almost every other `gcloud` command, `gcloud container images` commands call Google's implementation of the Docker Registry APIs. You can observe this by appending `--log-http` to `gcloud container images` commands.

All this to say that there is **no** Google Python SDK for interacting with this service.

Another quirk is that Google Cloud Platform projects *own* Google Container Registry registries but the mapping is non-trivial. It is often `gcr.io/${PROJECT}` but can be `us.gcr.io/${PROJECT}`. The following script assumes (!) `gcr.io/${PROJECT}`

The code that you include in your question is bash. In that spirit (and given the above), here's a script that does what you need.

Please be **very** careful as, if you include the delete command, this script will irrevocably delete **all** images in **every** project except `${EXCLUDE}`

### PROCEED WITH CARE

#### Unsafe

```sh
# Exclude this project
EXCLUDE="devops"

PROJECTS=$(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")

# Projects accessible to current user
for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  printf "Project: %s\n" ${PROJECT}
  if [ "${PROJECT}" == "${EXCLUDE}" ]
  then
    printf "Excluding Repository: %s\n" ${PROJECT}
  else
    printf "Including Repository: %s\n" ${PROJECT}
    # Images in ${PROJECT} repository
    IMAGES=$(gcloud container images list --project=${PROJECT})
    for IMAGE in ${IMAGES}
    do
      printf "Deleting Image: %s\n" ${IMAGE}
      # Image delete command goes here
    done
  fi
done
```

#### Unsafer

Replace the `#` comment with:

```sh
gcloud container images delete ${IMAGE} --project=${PROJECT}
```

#### Unsafest

Replace the `#` comment with:

```sh
gcloud container images delete ${IMAGE} --project=${PROJECT} --quiet
```

#### Less Awful

It would be less risky to provide the script with a list of Projects (Repositories) that you wish to be included in the purge. But, this script is still dangerous:

```sh
# Include these projects
PROJECTS=("first" "second" "third")

# Projects accessible to current user
for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS[@]}
do
  printf "Including Repository: %s\n" ${PROJECT}
  # Images in ${PROJECT} repository
  IMAGES=$(gcloud container images list --project=${PROJECT})
  for IMAGE in ${IMAGES}
  do
    printf "Deleting Image: %s\n" ${IMAGE}
    # Image delete command goes here
  done
fi
```

To reiterate **PLEASE PROCEED WITH CARE**

Deleting Images is **irrevocable** and you will be unable to recover deleted images

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify we are talking [Google Continaer Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry) not about [Google Source Repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories). In order to manage GCR images I would recommend you [GCR-cleaner](https://github.com/sethvargo/gcr-cleaner) tool which finds and deletes old images based on different [criteria](https://github.com/sethvargo/gcr-cleaner#payload--parameters).

Comment: if i want to do the same in python ,do i get any scripts where i want to delete all images in a repository except image named "devops"  in gcloud

Comment: You need to change --filter componenet with appropriate condition. Something like you need to check "image" name in list and if it is not "devops" delete it.